# Setting up OAuth authentication for a Java Twitter application using HttpClient 4.2.1

Tags: java, rest, twitter, oauth, httpclient

I am building a twitter app in Java that requires OAuth authentication and I am trying to use HttpClient 4.2.1 for the ReST transactions.  Does anyone have a code example on how to set up the credentials for OAuth authentication that includes a Consumer key, etc?

for example basic Auth:

```
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("twitter.com", 80, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), 
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
```

Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9939775/1467115.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/)? It should do everything you need, so you can use it as it is or as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scribe](http://www.richestlifestyle.com/richest-african-presidents/). It's documentation is detailed and lists other Apis you can access.